# Unable to refresh Sandboxes

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

[image]

Hi, I am a System Administrator in our application. I am about to refresh a sandbox but the Refresh link does not appear. The type of sandboxes are developer and full. Both sandboxes 'next refresh available' are set to 'Now'. Please help.

FYI: I was able to do a sandbox refresh a week ago. I have a “View Setup and Configuration” and “Modify All Data” permission. I am a System Administrator.

Org in NA8

Comment: so you are refreshing full copy sandbox and a week ago you refreshed once ?

Answer (score 7):

This could very well be because you have exceeded your Sandbox limit.  I see that you have 0 available and you are using 2 full sandboxes.  Do you pay for 2 full sandboxes?  When you exceed your limit, SF doesnt allow you to refresh any of your sandboxes, not just the sandboxes in question.

I'm guessing that you have exceeded your limit and need to consolidate and/or change a full sandbox to a developer sandbox to fix your issue.

**From SF Help**

> Salesforce deactivates all refresh links if you have exceeded your
>   sandbox limit

**AND**

> If you have reduced the number of sandboxes you purchased, but you
>   still have more sandboxes of a specific type than allowed, you will be
>   required to match your sandboxes to the number of sandboxes that you
>   purchased. For example, if you have two Full sandboxes but purchased
>   only one, you cannot refresh your Full sandbox as a Full sandbox.
>   Instead, you must choose one Full sandbox to convert to a smaller
>   sandbox, such as a Developer Pro or a Developer sandbox, depending on
>   which types you have available.

**See here for more information**

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_manage.htm&language=en_US

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_create.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and ended up deleting the sandbox and recreating it from scratch. As it was being refreshed it was essentially doing the same process.

Would be good to see what the reason is for the refresh link to be missing....